# if "it is a date" then "do what I say" -

Tags: python

How do I write an if statement trying to identify if a variable is a date in the format %Y-%m-%d or %Y-%m?

Like this:

```
for i in list:  
    for element in i:  
        if element is a date:  
            list2.append(element)
```

Where list is:
[['Date', 'Value'], ['2002-03', '12.9']]

i's are:
['Date', 'Value'] and ['2002-03', '12.9']

elements are:
'Date', 'Value', '2002-03', '12.9'

Comment: this package can help you identify variable that apply to date format datetime.datetime.strptime(element, '%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: I should substitute "a date" by datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d'), making the line look like "if element is datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d')"?

Comment: What type of objects are your elements? Do you have some sample input data for us?

Comment: yes, you may try it with good input i.e. '2014-11-20' or bad info 'XXX'

Comment: Do you explicitly want to support only those two date formats, or do you want to support any reasonable date format?

Comment: "list" is [['Date', 'Value'], ['2002-03', '12.9'], ['2002-04', '12.5'], ['2002-05', '11.9'], "i's" are ['Date', 'Value'], ['2002-03', '12.9'], elements are 'Date', 'Value', '2002-03' and '12.9'

Comment: I want to support only those two date formats by now :)

Comment: @abutremutante, please see my answer below. it should do the trick, but notice i haven't checked it so it might need some minor refinements.

Comment: If a value looks like  a date but isn't a valid date, should the test pass or fail? For example, February 32nd  `2012-02-32`.

Comment: [6.2. `re` — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that your input is a string, you may use the following validation using datetime package.

```
try:
    datetime.datetime.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError("format should be YYYY-MM-DD")
```

adapting this to your scenario :

```
list = [['Date', 'Value'], ['2002-03', '12.9'],['2001-01','11.6']]
list2=[]
for i in list:
    for element in i:
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(element, '%Y-%m')
            list2.append(element)
        except ValueError:
            continue
print list2
```

output was :

```
['2002-03', '2001-01']
```

Comment: It is getting me a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name because `str()` function.

Comment: @abutremutante, i've now check it, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to write a function that attempts to parse the value as a date, looping over all of the formats you want to support. If it is able to parse, return `True` (or, you could return the parsed value), and return `False` if none of the formats work:

```
def is_date(s):
    for format in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%Y-%m'):
        try:
            d = datetime.strptime(s , format)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return False
```

Applying this to your code, it would look like this:

```
for i in list:  
    for element in i:  
        if is_date(element):  
            list2.append(element)
```

Comment: it is returning all false :/ if it is a string it doesnt recognize as a date?

Comment: @abutremutante: if it's returning false, you're passing in data that's not valid. When I use data like `list = [['Date', 'Value'], ['2002-03', '12.9'],['2001-01','11.6']]` it works for me.